# What Event is fired when Access is leaving one record and moving to next?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am developing a MS Access 2016 application with bound controls on Forms.  Late in the process I decided I want a multi-select listbox.

From what I can see, you can't bind a multi-select listbox to a table.   I'm okay with parsing the listbox when about to leave that record, and putting a comma separated list of values in a bound, non-visible text box.  And then on arriving at the new record, setting the values in the listbox based on the values in that record's textbox.

The Current event lets me know when I arrive at a new record, but is there an event that lets me know I'm leaving a record?  Before Update only works if the current record is changed, not just navigating to a new record.  I suspect I'm missing something real basic.

Comment: just use listbox `on change` event to update the hidden textbox?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse a field and manually update it to a table, use the *Before Insert* and *Before Update* events. Don't do anything with navigation, because then you're likely too late.

Also, make sure to dirty the form when the value of the list box changes (`Me.Dirty = True` in the *On Change* event), so the update fires when navigating.

Or, like krish KM says, just make sure your text box changes every time your listbox changes.

That's more reliable than accounting for navigation, filtering, closing the form, manually saving, etc.

Comment: @ Erik - I'm not sure if you are suggesting setting `Me.Dirty = True` , I didn't think this was possible ? I thought you had to alter the forms data to force that change?

Comment: @Minty Nope, you can test it if you don't take my word for it. Add an event handler to the before update event of a bound form, and run `Me.Dirty = True` and then `DoCmd.GoToRecord` (that's the next record by default). The event handler will fire, even though you haven't changed a thing. The record selector also changes to the edit pencil after executing `Me.Dirty = True`.

Comment: @ Erik - I believe you ! I'm sure I had read somewhere that it was only able to be set to False. But that doesn't make sense as it's a "normal" property.

Comment: I'm still trying to get some time today for this, but it appears the solution is to use the Listbox's on Exit event to parse the list values to the text box, the the Form's Current event to parse from textbox to listbox.  The solutions above made me stop thinking of Form events only, and consider a control event to meet my needs.

Comment: Note that parsing on the listbox exit event is suboptimal, closing the form while the listbox has focus can cause that event not to fire, and entering and exiting the listbox repetitively causes you to parse it each time. As said, I recommend parsing only when values are actually getting committed (so on update/insert) and dirtying as soon as a value changes.